# Access custom attrubutes from Cython

Tags: cython, spacy

In some place of my code I need to know what is the number of sentence that a token belongs to, so I assign a custom attribute as follows:

```py
from spacy.tokens import Token
Token.set_extension('number', default=0)
```

After that, I want to use fast loops over tokens with Cython and access this attribute on C++ level. I know that we have:

```
Token.get_struct_attr
```

but it does not seem to work the following way:

```python
def traverse_doc(Doc doc):
    cdef int n_tokens = len(doc)
    cdef tokens = []
    cdef attr_hash = doc.vocab.strings.add('number')
    for token in doc.c[:n_tokens]: 
        tokens.append(Token.get_struct_attr(&token, attr_hash))
```

This code produces the following tuple for each token:

```
(0, None, None, None)
```

0 seems to be a default value of attribute, but it does not pay attention to the value that I assign to this attribute.

What is the proper way to access custom attributes?

Comment: Without having tested it, I doubt if `for token in doc.c[:n_tokens]` does what you want. I don't think Cython can treat a C pointer as an iterable. You should probably do `for n in range(n_tokens)` then `&(doc.c[n])` to get the pointer. It's hard to guess what your current code is doing though

Answer (score 0):

`Token.get_struct_attr` defaults to `0` if the attribute isn't found (or, more precisely, it delegates to `Lexeme.get_struct_attr`, which defaults to `0` – [see here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/f1c3108d52e3306a8f2c91b1f71d9d69b88ac672/spacy/lexeme.pxd#L91)). The fact that the extension's default value is `0` is just a slightly confusing coincidence. Custom extension attributes defined by the user aren't stored as C data, because they can be *anything* and thus can't be typed.

So instead of the `doc.c`, you need to check the **Python `doc`** at the given token index:

```py
for i in range(n_tokens):
   # Option 1: Use the ._ attribute
   number = doc[i]._.number
   # Option 2: Use the .get method with string attribute
   number = doc[i]._.get('number')
```